# WINDOW function alternative in HAVING Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, having-clause

I'm trying to get the oldest processing date on each product like this:

```
select prod_id, prod_name, prod_date, min(prod_date) over (partition by prod_id) as min_prod_date
from dim_product
where prod_name in ('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz')
having prod_date = min_prod_date
```

This gives me the error:

> ORA-00904: "min_prod_date": invalid identifier

So I tried to use the min() function in the having clause which gave me the error:

> ORA-30483: window  functions are not allowed here

As an alternative I modified my query like this:

```
with temp as(
select prod_id, prod_name, prod_date, min(prod_date) over (partition by prod_id) as min_prod_date
    from dim_product
    where prod_name in ('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz')
    having prod_date = min_prod_date))
select * from temp where prod_date = min_prod_date
```

Is this the right way to do things or Is there any other efficient method?

Comment: Your alternative isn't quite equivalent to what you seemed to want to do in the original query. However, I guess the "alternative" is closer to what you need. Namely: Do you need the `min_prod_date` for each `prod_id` (one row for each distinct `prod_id`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses `rank()` in a subquery:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        prod_id, 
        prod_name, 
        prod_date, 
        rank() over(partition by prod_id order by prod_date) rn
    from dim_product
    where prod_name in ('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz')
) t
where rn = 1
```

As an alternative, you may also want to consider filtering with a correlated subquery:

```
select prod_id, prod_id, prod_date
from dim_product d
where d.prod_name in ('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz') and d.prod_date = (
    select min(d1.prod_date)
    from dim_product d1
    where d1.prod_id = d.prod_id and d1.prod_name in ('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz')
)
```

For efficiency in the latter query, you want an index on `(prod_name, prod_id, prod_date)`.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like aggregation:

```
select prod_name, min(prod_date)
from dim_product
where prod_name in ('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz')
group by prod_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your query as sub query and fetch the desired output as following:

```
Select prod_id, prod_name, prod_date
From
(select prod_id, prod_name, prod_date, 
        min(prod_date) over (partition by prod_id) as min_prod_date
from dim_product
where prod_name in ('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz'))
Where prod_date = min_prod_date
```

Cheers!!